# Why is $A$ similar to $D$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-calculus

Let $A\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
   {{x_1}} & 0  \\
   0 & {{x_2}}  \\
\end{array}} \right)\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
   1  \\
   1  \\
\end{array}} \right) = \lambda \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
   {{x_1}}  \\
   {{x_2}}  \\
\end{array}} \right)$

where $A \in {M_2}(R)$ and all $a_{ij}\ge 0$, and for some $x_1\ge 0$ ,$x_2 \ge 0$.

Can we say that $ A$  is diagonally
similar to a  matrix, all of whose row sums are equal?

Comment: Hint: note that \lambda is an eigenvalue of A with eigenvector associated (x_1,x_2)

Comment: @vvnitram - Please more guide, i dont understand, why  is $A$ similar to .....??

Comment: @ThomasAndrews  I edited this post.

Comment: Just one English-language thing. "Let" is used to define $A$ exactly, not to assume something is true about $A$. In this case, you could write: "Assume $A\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\x_2\end{pmatrix} = \lambda \begin{pmatrix}x_1\\x_2\end{pmatrix}$ where ..."

Comment: Sorry - deleting my previous comment - I had misread... however, it is true that "for some $x_1\ge 0, x_2\ge 0$" allows for $x_1= x_2 =0$, which gives $A0 =0$ as equation, which holds for all $A$ - so implies 'nothing'. So I don't think I understand your question... And by 'diagonally similar' do you mean 'similar to a diagonal matrix'?

Comment: @petera g - Yes,dear 'peter a g', what about $x_1>0 $ and $x_2>0$?